# Copy constructor error

Tags: c++

I need someone to show me what is wrong with this code. I don't know what's wrong with it. I know the code doesn't do anything meaningful and it can't be used. I created it only to know how copy constructors work.

```
class test
{
  public:

    int* value;

  public:

    int getvalue()
    {return *value;};

    test(int x){ value = new int(x);};

    test(const test& a)
    {
        value=new int;

        *value = a.getvalue();
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you really want to use pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the declaration of `getvalue()` to `int getvalue() const`, since you're trying to call `getvalue()` on a const reference in your copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stray ; after each method definition, so will not compile.

```
class test { public:

 int* value;

 public:

 int getvalue()
 {return *value;}

 test(int x){ value= new int(x);}

 test(const test& a)
 {
   value=new int;

   *value = a.getvalue();
 }


 };
```

Also, I'd avoid 'test' as a class name; depending on your platform if might be a macro or some other in-scpe name. Use "MyTest" or somesuch.

Comment: The solution was declaring getvalue() as a const member function. but thank you i know i put a lot of extra ; in my code. :D:D

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I last wrote C++, but here goes:

I'm not sure why you're declaring value to be an int pointer; did you mean to make it an int?

```
class test
{ 
    private:

        int value;

    public:

        test(int x)
        { 
           value = new int(x);
        }

        int getValue()
        {
           return value;
        }

        test(const test & a)
        {
            value = a.getValue();
        }
};
```

Comment: I know my code doesnt do anything but its for learning purposes. that line "int= new int(x)" wont compile. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I tried making the getvalue() function const and it worked. The problem was that I passed the test class as a const reference and because I didn't declare the getvalue() function const the compiler thought the function was going to change something in that reference.